# Query with dropdown not working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

In my Google sheet I'm getting an error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN:

I've added a dropdown so the formula will auto-update depending on the tab selected.

Here's the formula that I'm getting an error:

```
=AVERAGE(query(""&B1&""&C1&"!!A2:I","Select Col9 where Col2='"&A5&"'"))
```

And here's the formula that's working:

```
=AVERAGE(query('2019年5月'!A$2:I,"Select I where B='"&A5&"'"))
```

Can somebody help me with this, please?

Comment: Welcome. Please see if you can edit your answer and provide a link to a sample spreadsheet or/and form. Your question is quite vague. Also please read [ask] and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY({INDIRECT(B1&C1&"!A2:I")}, "select Col9 where Col2 = '"&A5&"'"))
```

[image: 0]